# pi sense and exporting data

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, node-red

I'm new to node red.  I've added the PI Sense the Raspberry PI and want to retrieve just the acceleration Z axis as show below (extracted from the debug window). I've written a function to extract just the acceleration and pass that on the flow.  However, the function isn't work.  Please help?

```
Function
var z = msg.payload.acceleration.z;
return [z];
```

.

```
Extracted from the debug window
19/03/2017, 20:59:06node: fa789a6a.8d4f98
motion : msg : Object
object
topic: "motion"
payload: object
acceleration: object
x: 0.0279
y: -0.3536
z: 0.9068
gyroscope: object
x: 0.0011
y: 0.0022
z: -0.0004
orientation: object
roll: 338.8994
pitch: 358.3852
yaw: 123.876
compass: 124
_msgid: "51b99603.7dac98"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a msg object from a function node not just a value.

Something like this:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.acceleration.z;
return msg;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to use "msg.payload = msg.payload.acceleration.z;" instead of var.  Now i can just see the results of just "z" (Well what i believe is "z").   However the function displays "TypeError: Cannot read property 'z' of undefined".  What do i need to do to resolve this issue? See full listing from debug below: 

`20/03/2017, 18:22:03node: fa789a6a.8d4f98
motion : msg : Object
object
topic: "motion"
payload: 0.9209
_msgid: "151978a5.22d8b7"
20/03/2017, 18:22:03node: 95b5672d.fb8858
function : (error)
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'z' of undefined"`